# How to change stock of a product loading by sku in magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

How can we load a product by sku and then change the stock status and quantity of that product. I am using magento 2.1.1 CE, and I have this situation in which I need to use only the sku to perform my activities on the product. I want to change the stock quantity and status using the sku.

Comment: Use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Shine using that only but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

In magento2 CatalogInventory is different module, you can get the stock item by simply using this class `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry` method `getStockItemBySku($productSku, $scopeId = null)` or `getStockItem($productId, $scopeId = null)` .like below:

```
$stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($productSku);
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$stockItem->save();
```

Comment: Upvote for the reduction to minimum. No product->save no stockItem->setData() ... works straight and clean